# Communication pattern for child objects to parents

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, c#-4.0

I am actually developping a multithreaded game server in C#. I am trying to create it as unit-testable as possible.

As of now, the pattern I started using resemble to something like this :

A **Server** class is instanciated:

- Serves to start and shutdown the server

OnStart the Server instanciate the **ConnnectionManager** :

- Contains an instance of the class **ConnectionPool**
- Serves to accept asynchronously connections (via TCPListener.BeginAcceptSocket)
- When a socket is accepted an instance of **ClientConnection** is created ans added to the list in **ConnectionsPool**

The class **ConnectionsPool** :

- Responsible to add and remove active connections to the pool, managed as a list

The class **ClientConnection** :

- Responsible to receive the data via Socket.BeginReceive
- When all is received, an instance of **SocketHandler** is created (basically parse the socket content and run actions)

The schema should look like this :
Server -> ConnectionManager -> ConnectionsPool -> ClientConnection -> SocketHandler

**The problem** :
When I am inside the SocketHandler, how can I affect another player ? (for example, player A hits player B: I need to get the instance of the player B inside ConnectionsPool and update his HP property) or even update the server itself (say call the shutdown method on the Server class)

I assume to have 3 choices :

- Transform all important classes (Server + ConnectionsPool) into
  static classes > drawback:  can't be unit tested
- Transform all important classes into Singleton classes > drawback :
  difficult to test
- Inject inside child constructor the instances of important classes >
  drawback : less readable code since a lot of information is passed

The goal here is to make this all unit testable using best practices while keeping a simple approach.

I received a suggestion to inject a delegate to childs which is similar to the 3rd method, but I am unsure about unit testing this and the real effect since everything is multithreaded of course.

What would be the best architecture choice here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme I find is that networking code is not really unit testable, and should be isolated from the code you do wish to test (the Player object, for example). To me it seems you have tightly coupled a Player to a ClientConnection, which might make it less testable. I also think that coupling a Player with his connection is probably violating the SRP, since they have very distinct responsibilities.

I've written a system which seems similar to what you wish to acheive, and I done so by linking a player to a connection only via delegates and interfaces. I have a separate World and Server class library, and a third project, Application, which references the two, and creates an instance of Server and World. My Player object is in the World, and a Connection in the Server - these two projects do not reference one another, so you can consider Player without any terms of networking.

The method I use is to make SocketHandler abstract, and implement a concrete handler in the Application project. The handler has a reference to the world object, which can be passed to it on creation. (I do so by means of factory classes -  eg, ClientConnectionFactory (in Application), where the Server knows only of abstract Connections and Factories.)

```
public class ClientConnectionFactory : IConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly World world;

    public ClientConnectionFactory(World world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    Connection IConnectionFactory.Create(Socket socket) {
        return new ClientConnection(socket, world);
    }
}
```

The ClientConnection can then forward the World reference to it's handler, along with any information the handler requires about the Connection itself, such as the Send methods in particular. Here I just pass the Connection object itself to the Handler.

```
public ClientConnection(Socket socket, World world)
    : base(socket) {
    this.handler = new ClientHandler(this, world);
    ...
}
```

Most of the coordination between the game logic and the networking is then contained inside the ClientHandler, and perhaps any other sister objects it references.

```
class ClientHandler : SocketHandler
{
    private readonly Connection connection;
    private readonly World world;

    public ClientHandler(Connection connection, World world) {
        this.connection = connection;
        this.world = world;
        ...
    }

    //overriden method from SocketHandler
    public override void HandleMessage(Byte[] data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The rest involves the ClientHandler creating it's Player object, assigning delegates or interfaces to update actions, and then adding the player to the pool of players in World. Initially I done this with a list of events in Player, which I subscribe to with methods in the ClientHandler (which knows of the Connection), but it turned out that there were dozens of events in the Player object which became a mess to maintain.

The option I went for was to use abstract notifiers in the World project on the player. For example, for movement I would have an IMovementNotifier object in Player. In Application, I would create a ClientNotifier which implements this interface and does the relevant sending of data to the client. The ClientHandler would create the ClientNotifier and pass it to it's Player object.

```
class ClientNotifier : IMovementNotifier //, ..., + bunch of other notifiers
{
    private readonly Connection connection;

    public ClientHandler(Connection connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    void IMovementNotifier.Move(Player player, Location destination) {
        ...
        connection.Send(new MoveMessage(...));
    }
}
```

The ClientHandler ctor can be changed to instantiate this notifier.

```
public ClientHandler(Connection connection, World world) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.world = world;
    ...
    var notifier = new ClientNotifier(this);
    this.player = new Player(notifier);
    this.world.Players.Add(player);
}
```

So the resulting system is one where ClientHandler is responsible for all incoming messages and events, and ClientNotifier handles all outgoing stuff. These two classes are quite difficult to test as they contain a lot of other crap. Networking can't really be unit tested anyway, but the Connection object in these two classes can be mocked. The World library is entirely unit testable without any consideration of networking components, which is what I wanted to acheive in my design anyway.

It's a big system, and I've not covered much of it here, but hope this can give you some hints. Ask me if you'd like any more specific information on it.

If I could give any more advice, it would be to avoid any static or singletons - they'll come back to bite you. Favour increasing complexity if you need to as an alternative, but document where you need to. The system I have might seem complex to a maintainer, but is well documented. To a user it's particularly simple to use. Main is essentially

```
var world = new World();
var connectionFactory = new ClientConnectionFactory(world);
var server = new Server(settings.LocalIP, settings.LocalPort, connectionFactory);
```

Comment: Great answer! I'll look on this tonight and see what this would impact on the current code.

Comment: I looked in detail your post but I have some hesitations here. There is a World DLL with a World class and a Player class. There is a Networking DLL with a ClientConnection class (and handlers). How can you inject an instance of the World class to the ClientConnection if Networking don't have any reference for World ?

Comment: I wasn't very clear on that sorry. The Server library contains an abstract Connection class. The ClientConnection class is located in the Application project, and subclasses Connection.

Comment: With refactoring it seems it's going the good way. Thanks for the suggestion!